# Make anti-join on two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to make an antijoin using two columns. I cannot understand how to do so. Here is my problem description:

I have two tables. Each table has three columns: date, product_description & $sales. 
I receive an updated table everyday, with the data for the last day (lets call this updated table or **ut**). In the backend, I am maintaining a historical data of the last few months (lets call this historical table or **ht**). Using SQL, I want to add the new table to the historical data.

To cater to duplication, I want to join on date and ID. ID is included in the product_description. In a product_description of '1234 - Toy Pokemon', ID is 1234. Here is what my script looks like:

```
select
*
from ut

union all

-- exclude data from historical data that is going to be replaced by new data

select
ht.*
from ht
left join ut on ht.date = ut.date and substring_index(ht.product_description,'-',1) = substring_index(ut.product_description,'-',1)
where ut.date and substring_index(ut.product_description,'-',1) is null
```

However, this does not work.

Could anyone help me in how to solve this problem?

Comment: question reduced to a manageable size

Comment: I can only refer you to my previous comment

Comment: To exclude some id to be not select You would add WHERE id NOT IN (SELELCT id FROM WHERE Or you join 'Only the Values that are not excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'I want to add the new table to the historical data.' then you don't need the bit before and up to the union. For example using your second select as the basis and fixing the where clause.

```
drop table if exists ut,ht;

create table ut(dt date,product_description varchar(20), sales int);
create table ht(dt date,product_description varchar(20), sales int);

insert into ht values
('2020-04-01','1 - aaa',10),('2020-04-02','1 - aaa',10);

insert into ut values
('2020-03-01','1 - aaa',20),('2020-04-01','1 - aaa',20);

insert into ht
select ut.dt,ut.product_description,ut.sales
from ut
left join ht on ht.dt = ut.dt and 
            substring_index(ht.product_description,'-',1) = substring_index(ut.product_description,'-',1) 
where ht.dt is null and ht.product_description is null;

select * from ht;

+------------+---------------------+-------+
| dt         | product_description | sales |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| 2020-04-01 | 1 - aaa             |    10 |
| 2020-04-02 | 1 - aaa             |    10 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 - aaa             |    20 |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

You could also consider a trigger on ut or an exists clause.

Comment: Thank You! I think I've got the answer that I needed through the script that you wrote! You're a life saver!!

Comment: So If I were to do things the way I wrote in my question, I would write the 100% same script but with "where ut.date is null and ut.product_description is null"  in the last line

Comment: No, the code is being driven from ut so ut columns will never be null and you want to insert the missing value to ht which will be null if the ut entries are not found.

Comment: ahh ok I meant in the script in my question. because in my script I derive from ht (after the union). so my question above was for my own script

Comment: Also, I want values in ut replacing values in ht for the same date and product id. That means the final combined table should have ('2020-04-01','1 - aaa',20) from the ut and NOT the old value ('2020-04-01','1 - aaa',10) from ht. That is because new data takes precedence over old one

Comment: So a simplified version of the question is you want to insert or update ht from ut. Do you have any indexes on HT and why are you substringin product_description?

Comment: I got the answer actually from your original answer. Thanks a lot!